# Why doe's hover function doesn't work? (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, function

I've been asked to change an image to another, whenever a user hover over a link.

I wrote the following code-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".block-boxes-os_sv_list_box h1 a").on("hover", function(){
         $(".image-style-profile-thumbnail").attr("src","https://openscholar.huji.ac.il/sites/default/files/buberinstitute/files/buber_logo.png?m=1554038720");
    });

})
```

And yet it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

At the moment- the result is that nothing happens

Comment: Please include your html, without we can't point out the problem

Comment: Could you please attach the DOM element as well, where you want to do this?

Comment: Why are you doing this with jquery and an image - I'm guessing your image is inside the anchor but that is a guess from your comments on various answers.  Please show your html too in order for us to give you an better answer.  If this is an imagein the anchor, then why not just use a background image and use css to change it on hover, much easier

Comment: I'm overriding a Drupal system. i have a page with 20+ <article>that contains an <img> and html. when hovering the <h1>,the specific <img> of the article should be replace. and when not hovering- the original <img> needs to appear.

Answer (score 2):

*Deprecated as of jQuery 1.8: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave. Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which accepts one or two functions.*

> Source: http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes

I just write a working example with HTML, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".block-boxes-os_sv_list_box h1 a").hover(function() {
      $(".image-style-profile-thumbnail").attr("src","https://openscholar.huji.ac.il/sites/default/files/buberinstitute/files/buber_logo.png?m=1554038720");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-boxes-os_sv_list_box">
  <h1>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </h1>
</div>

<image src="" class="image-style-profile-thumbnail" alt="" />
```

Comment: Why should he try this? What was changed? What is the OP doing wrong?

Comment: @JamesHill From the doc: "*Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave"*".

Comment: That should have been explanation in answer.... *"I made changes"* is virtually meaningless

Comment: @iArcadia, I know that...I may or may not have the gold jquery badge :-). The point is, if it's not in the answer, the answer is worthless. This isn't a "fix my code" site, it's a learning tool for everyone.

Comment: thank you. now the situation is that when hovering one link- all the images with class ".image-style-profile-thumbnail" are been replaced. and it doesn't go back to the first img.

Comment: @JamesHill I didn't understand your first comment this way! But you're right

Comment: @JamesHill I just update the description with all clarifications, I hope you are satisfy now. Thanks

Comment: @Leaor, in case you want only a single image to be replaced on hover, and not all, as you commented, you should make sure that the relevant image to be replaced should have a unique id attribute in the html, and to refer to that id using the jquery, instead of referring to the class.

Answer (score 2):

You're just using the wrong keyword for hover when used with `.on()`

```js
$("button").on("mouseover", function() {
  console.log('works')
  $("img").attr("src", "https://placehold.it/100x200");
});

$("button").on("hover", function() {
  console.log('not working')
  $("img").attr("src", "https://placehold.it/100x200");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Change on hover</button>
<img src="https://placehold.it/200x300" />
```

Comment: The event should be `mouseenter mouseleave` as `hover` with one callback was for these two events at once.